# How can I pass an id to a partial view controller method using ajax?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to refresh a partial view with this piece of jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    setInterval(RefreshAgenda, 3000);
});

function RefreshAgenda() {
    var data = {"id":"@Model.Id"};
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Meetings/AgendaPartial",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (response) {
            $('#_Agenda').html(response);
        }
    });
}
```

The controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AgendaPartial(string id)
{
    if (id == null) return NotFound();
    if (!Guid.TryParse(id, out Guid parsedId)) return NotFound();
    Meeting meeting = await db.Meetings
        .Include(a => a.Agenda)
        .Where(m => m.Id == parsedId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    return PartialView("_Agenda", auto.Map<MeetingViewModel>(meeting));
}
```

`@Model.Id` contains a valid `id`, but when we get to the method, `id` = `null`, and a 404 is returned, as dictated by the method.

If I try to access the method directly by typing /Meetings/AgendaPartial/{id}, the partial view is successfully returned.

How can I change the script to successfully send the `id` to the controller method?

Answer (score 0):

After posting this question, I stumbled upon another way of doing it:

```
function RefreshAgenda() {
    var data = { id: "@Model.Id.ToString()" };

    $.post('/Meetings/AgendaPartial', data,
        function (response) {
            $('#_Agenda').html(response);
        });
}
```

Now it works! :)